# Spring @PathVariable create custom object

Tags: spring, http-request-parameters

I have an entity in my application that have a composed **ID**.
In my controller I get this entity using the `@PathVariable` in this way:

```
@RequestMapping("/{year}/{code}")
public MyCustomObj get(@PathVariable Integer year, @PathVariable Integer code){
    return myCustomObjRepository.findOne(new CustomId(year, code));
}
```

Is it possible, using some component like `WebArgumentResolver`, to make my method works in this way:

```
@RequestMapping("/{customObj}")
public MyCustomObj get(@PathVariable CustomId id){
    return myCustomObjRepository.findOne(id);
}
```

having a the URL like: `/application/2013/06`

Comment: Do you mind an http redirect with filters?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bind Path variables to a custom model object in spring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17149425/bind-path-variables-to-a-custom-model-object-in-spring)

Comment: Ops...I din't see it...so the question can be closed...thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by registering a custom filter and overriding the doFilterMethod as shown below.

```
 public void doFilter(ServletRequest arg0, ServletResponse arg1,
        FilterChain chain){
 HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) arg0;
 HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) arg1;
 String args = request.getRequestURI();
 //get your year and code
 MyCustomObj obj = new CustomId(year, code);
 response.sendRedirect("someURL/obj");
 }
```