# Spring @PathVariable as a Year

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I've got an endpoint that is:

```
api/entities/{year}
```

and my function looks like:

```
get(@PathVariable(name = "year") Year year)
```

But when I try to hit the endpoint I, expectedly, get an error that it can't convert from type String to type Year. I obviously need something like a @DateTypeFormat, but that doesn't really work.

Is there a way to format the incoming value to be a Year, or should I rework my API to not use a Year?

Comment: My guess would be that the api receive a `String` when you call it and try to map it into a `Year`. `Year` does not have a contructor using a String, so it will likely failed ?

Comment: Maybe this can help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17149425/bind-path-variables-to-a-custom-model-object-in-spring

Comment: Check `@RequestBody`, I dont thin `@PathVariable` and `@RequestParam` can be objects

Comment: You could accept it as a `String` and attempt to convert after the endpoint is hit?

Comment: yeah, @RoadEx, that's what it seems like. Since it's just receiving a String, I was curious if there was some sort of formatter that I could use like DateTypeFormat

Comment: You may use custom types when providing a conversion from `String` - see e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/gipyw/index.html for an example

Comment: @dimwittedanimal Yeah, I think that's what i'm going to have to do. I just went with accepting it as a String and then passing in Year.parse(year) to the Service. If you want to add that as an answer i'll accept it.

Comment: I recomend you take a look to this post: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17149425/bind-path-variables-to-a-custom-model-object-in-spring

Comment: Since you weren't specific, is this a `java.time.Year`? Spring ought to support that OOTB by now, and if it doesn't, you should file a feature request.

Comment: @chrylis yeppers! Just a regular ol' Java time.Year

Comment: File it in the Spring JIRA, then. This should be supported by default converter set. (And as a side note, this should *usually* be a query parameter instead of a path part--`/entities?year=`, but that doesn't change the converter question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could accept it as a `String` and attempt to convert after the endpoint is hit?

Answer (score 7):

You can do something like:

```
public class YearHandlerMethodArgumentResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {

    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter methodParameter) {
        return methodParameter.getParameterType().equals(Year.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter methodParameter,
                                  ModelAndViewContainer modelAndViewContainer,
                                  NativeWebRequest nativeWebRequest,
                                  WebDataBinderFactory webDataBinderFactory) throws Exception {
        final String yearFromPath = nativeWebRequest.xxx();

        return Year.from(yearFromPath);
    }

}
```

**Then** 
Register it in your spring-context

Comment: IMHO, this should be the accepted answer. The other answer is more of a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way is to accept an `Integer` and then convert it if you really need a `Year` type.

You can register your own `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` to do the conversion for you although it looks like too much boiler plate for this scenario it is the more elegant.

Another possibility is to handle it as a date, that conversion comes for free:

`@PathVariable(name = "year") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy") Date date`

You can later extract the year value in the form you prefer.